# Does IE 11 support offline storage, so web pages can work completely offline

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, offline-caching

**Background:**

I am building an html5, angularjs offline web appliation.

**Issue:**

My offline web application works in the offline mode in chrome and firefox.
But it fails to work in the offline mode in IE11 browser.

**Question:**

Does IE11 support applications to work in offline mode ?.

I am getting confusing messages after reading different forums like the one below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9c12adf3-aaac-480d-8bac-aa7667fc020d/viewing-the-offline-application-cache-ie11?forum=iewebdevelopment

It says that IE 11 wouldn't support offline storage....is it correct ?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps

Comment: That's IECustomizer MVP you've cited.  He's one of msdn's foremost authorities.  Why not log-in to that thread and ask him directly?  He posts practically daily.

Comment: That was quick.  [Follow the conversation *here*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ceb4b741-9563-44f5-b431-6acb929698da/does-ie11-support-application-cache-to-create-offline-web-applications).